# How can I name a list variable with its first element?

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm making lists for every line in the text file with the first element being "List[linenumber]", for example, "Line1". However, I need to name these lists so I can use each one later on in the program, so I need to name each list with the first element (e.g. *List1 = ["List1", "string", int]*)

```
    lines = 0
    user = input ("Enter GTIN-8 Code For Desired Product: ")
    with open('Task2.csv') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',', quotechar=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in reader:
            lines = int(lines)
            lines += 1
            lines = str(lines)
            lists = "List"
            lists = lists + lines
            lists = [lists] + row
            print (lists)
```

How can I do this? Is there a line of code I can add to the for loop?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: this is a bad idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have to do it this way and saving every list individually in a new variable?

In my opinion a better option would be to use a 2-dimensional List and accessing your elements via their indices, e.g. `lines[0][1]`. This would be a "list of lists", where the outer list contains your lines, each line in the format of another list.

You can read more about lists of lists [here](https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/).

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. You knocked me into my senses. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please always accept an answer, if it answers the question.

Comment: @NithilaLogathas besides this answer which is ok, you can also think in storing results (rows) in a dict, where the key is your wanted name. Maybe with the help of `enumerate()` in your `for` loop, to get the row index.